# How to install SDK in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

I once completely deleted Android Studio, but when I want to install it again, during installation, tick of SDK  is not checked and it is not installed.
The installation location of SDK cannot be determined, whatever I do

[image: 1]

I add ANDOID_HOME in environment variables in windows

I create C:\Android\Sdk SDK but But unfortunately SDK was not installed and

Answer (score 0):

I Think SDK is not in your system But you can download SDK from android official site for Android, mac or Linux.

Here is the link : https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools

And paste the SDK here : **C:\Android\Sdk**